# Yii checkBoxList сохраняет поле как Array

Tags: yii

Yii checkBoxList сохраняет поле как - Array. Как решить проблему, чтобы сохранял выбранные значения чекбокса. Спасибо, заранее

Comment: убедитесь в том, что вы правильно передаете параметры в checkBoxList

Comment: Решил сам:

   foreach ($_POST['Olovk'] as $pos => $data)
   {
    if (is_array($data))
    {
     $result[$pos] = implode(',', $data);
     $model->$pos=$result[$pos];
    }
   }